# How to get a Smart Card for the Cairo metro?

Tags: public-transport, egypt, cairo, contactless

According to [this article](https://egyptianstreets.com/2015/12/14/no-more-queues-egypt-introduces-smart-cards-for-cairo-metro/) Cairo has smart cards for their metro, however, it is unclear to me how I might go about getting one of these smart cards.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can buy student cards and charge them from one of the main stations like ATTABA, ABBASIYA, ROUD EL FARAG, SADAT. That’s if you’re a student in Egyptian universities or International universities in Egypt and for pupils as well.

For other people, you can get the card from any station for 10 E£ and charge it with up to 100 E£, It’s valid for 5 years.